# Encoding-Decoding string

Tags: java, android, string, encryption

Is there a way in Android/Java which encode the string in below-mentioned way:

```
Original String: "Today is a sunny day. I must go out."
```

apply encoding now

`Resulting string after encoding: "Today is a sunny day."`

Now decode the encoded string to get the original string:

`Original String: "Today is a sunny day. I must go out."`

Comment: Encoding/decoding or encrypting/decrypting?

Comment: That is not encoding and encryption does not help.

Comment: Am sorry am not much aware of these things. I just wanted to know if there is any way to accomplish the behavior?

Comment: I'm no encryption / encoding master, but I'm pretty sure that neither will do what you are trying to accomplish.  You can truncate strings, but I don't know that there is any way in any language to bring the original string back.

Comment: You'll most likey get a result string which looks like `Resulting string after encoding: "Er1502zx3AvhB_D0892F~1050{EF-D3:2zD"`

Answer (score 0):

Save the full text in a file or DB with the short version as the file name or DB key.

From the question:

key is "Today is a sunny day."
data is "Today is a sunny day. I must go out."

If it is just during the duration of the app you can use a dictionary/hash table such as teh Java HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to do is not quite clear.It is not called encoding.It is just string manipulation. It might be that I am not understanding the thing clearly.

```
String encoded = "Today is a sunny day. I must go out.";//Store encoded string here
String decoded = str.substring(0,str.indexOf('.')+1);//Store decoded string here
```

See if this helps...